# Laravel User Logout

Tags: php, authentication, logging, laravel-5.1

Hi I tried to implement logging out. I also added remember_token in users table. It gets updated when I log in but I am not able to log out with the following function. Is there more I need to add to log out?

```
public function doLogout(){
  Auth::logout();
  Session::forget('user');
  return Redirect::to('/#signin');
}
```

Comment: this should do the trick. what's the error it's showing?

Comment: I am not getting any error. I use Auth::check() to check if an user is logged in after I log out. I get true for this value

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, first create a route

```
Route::get('auth/logout', ['as' => 'auth.logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout']);
```

then add a link,

```
<a href="{{ route('auth.logout') }}">Logout</a>
```

or redirect.

```
public function doLogout(){
    return redirect()->route('auth.logout');
}
```

you can check this documentation for more informations 
http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#included-authenticating